# Ubuntu boot problem at start black screen white cursor

Tags: boot, hard-drive, drive

I recently swapped hard drives on my HP computer and when I swapped back to my Ubuntu one I get just a blinking cursor on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Boot-Repair tool? It is one of the suggested tools for boot repair on Ubuntu's Help pages.

Assuming you can/know how to change your BIOS settings to boot from a USB flash drive, you could use your Windows HDD to download it and make a bootable USB stick to try and repair GRUB with your Ubuntu HDD.

You would need to download a utility like UNetbootin **and** the Boot-Repair tool on your Windows OS, then once made you simply swap your Ubuntu HDD back into your machine and boot from your USB stick.

**1**. On your Windows OS, obtain UNetbootin from [here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). The UNetbootin tool is a simple .exe file that you can simply run; no permanent install is necessary.

**2**.  Download the Boot-Repair tool from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/). It will be in the form of an .ISO file that UNetbootin can read to create your bootable USB flash drive.

**3**.  Insert the USB flash drive you want to use into your computer.

**4**.  Run the UNetbootin tool you have already downloaded to install the Boot-Repair tool on the USB flash drive.

**5**.  In UNetbootin, you will have to select the Ubuntu distribution and version in the provided drop-down menus. Make sure you choose the appropriate version of Ubuntu that you have on your HDD (either 14.04_Live or 12.04_Live...I'm assuming at this point you have one of those, since you didn't specify which version of Ubuntu you have installed)

**6**.  Select the "Diskimage" radio button near the bottom, make sure "ISO" is selected in the dropdown box, then browse/select the Boot-Repair ISO file you downloaded.

**7**.  Make sure "USB Drive" is selected in the "Type" dropdown box, and assign any drive letter you wish (if you don't want the default drive letter it selects).

**8**.  Click OK, then give the UNetbootin tool a few minutes to create the USB drive.

**9**.  Power down your computer, and swap your Windows HDD for your Ubuntu HDD.

**10**. Power back on; if you have not already configured your BIOS to boot from USB, now is the time to do so.

**11**. Once your computer boots to the USB drive, use the Boot-Repair tool to repair GRUB. If you are not an advanced user, I would recommend using the default "Recommended Repair" option since you are not dual-booting another OS on that HDD.

Other detailed instructions can be found at these locations:

*https: //help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair*

*http: //sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair/*

I apologize that the above two links have the extra space; I can only post two links in total per post in these forums.

Hope this helps; make sure you let us know if this works, or if you need any more help. If you need more help, please make sure you are as detailed as you can be (computer type, Ubuntu version, any errors you may be getting, etc etc). The more detail we have, the better we can be of help.

***Alternately,*** you could use the Recovery Mode that is already installed with Ubuntu **if you can access it.**

When you power on your computer, hold the **Shift** key as soon as your BIOS screen finishes loading, or has almost finished loading. You should get some boot options, one of which will be **Choose Advanced Options for Ubuntu**.

The next screen, you should choose the first *recovery* option, which should look something like this:

`Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-39-generic (recovery mode)`

The third menu will provide several options, but in your case I believe the **dpkg** option, which attempts to restore broken packages, may be of help in restoring your Ubuntu system. Again, let us know if this helps or if you need further assistance.

Comment: Hey I tried parts of this thanks for your time and I wasn't using a USB I was swapping internal hard drives 1 with Windows 1 with Linux 14.04

Comment: I realize you were using two HDDs, one with Windows and the other with Ubuntu; the USB drive I was referring to is only used to repair the HDD with the Ubuntu install; it is easier to use the USB drive with the Boot-Repair tool than burning the utility to CD. Try using the whole method I described above instead of just parts and refer to the edits I made for more options. If it doesn't work, then edit your original question post with more details so we can help you figure out where to go from there. I know it's lengthy, but read my entire post; these options usually solve most problems.